# Robomongo query to return a list of ids

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I want to query my database in Mongo and then be able to copy and paste the list of ids the query returns.

I know I can project the `_id` like

```
db.getCollection('mymodel').find({}}, { _id: 1 })
```

But I want to be able to copy and paste the result as an array of ids, is there a way to achieve this with Robomongo/Mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_o7kjX3Kuuf) query you want?

Using `aggregate` add all `_id`s to a set:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": { "_id": null, "ids": { "$addToSet": "$_id" } }
  },
  {
    "$project": { "_id": 0 }
  }
])
```

And the ouput is similar to this, an array called `ids` with all `id`:

```json
"ids": [
   ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
   ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
   ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
   ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
   ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
   ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002")
]
```

You can use `$match` to filter the documents you want to get the `id` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JRXiXwL80PZ) example.